# Calculate average of time intervals

Tags: iphone

how to calculate average of time intervals in iphone development

Answer (score 2):

You could just keep all time intervals you'd ever seen, and average them each time. But a smarter way to do it is to use a technique called "Running average", whereby as new measurements come in you calculate a new average based on the 'old' average and the new value.  There's a mention of it [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1627-Create-A-Running-Average-Without-Storing-Individual-Values.htm) but it's not the clearest explanation.

Comment: +1, We also can look at [cumulative moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Cumulative_moving_average) formula in wiki.